# Suppress "Unused declaration of function" warning GCC

Tags: eclipse-cdt, unused-functions

I'm trying to suppress "Unused declaration of function" warning in GCC into a third party file for an embedded system.

I tried every combination of pragma ****attribute**((unused))** but the warnig is still there.

This is the declaration of a weak function:

```
void __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("Default_Handler")))
ADC1_IRQHandler(void);
```

And this is the waring:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
> Unused declaration of function 'ADC1_IRQHandler'    vectors_stm32f0xx.c /FW00_Application/system/src/cmsis  line 44 Code Analysis Problem

I tried:

```
void __attribute__ ((weak, unused, alias ("Default_Handler")))
ADC1_IRQHandler(void);
```

and:

```
void __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("Default_Handler")))  __attribute__ ((unused))
ADC1_IRQHandler(void);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

BR,
Federico

Comment: `Code Analysis Problem` Are you _sure_ this is a message from gcc? Please post the full gcc message as it is printed by gcc.

Comment: @KamilCuk you are right! Looking into the Eclipse Probolem windows, the type colum reports "Code Analysis Problem".

Comment: Then go to eclipse settings and disable detecting that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is related to "Eclipse Code Analysis" feature not to GCC.